# Use of adding xs, sm, md etc tags in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What's the use of adding xs, sm, md etc tags in bootstrap when it automatically handles the responsive-ness(layout handling on change in size of screen)? 
I understand that sometimes you'd want your controls to not stack for whatever reasons, so is then that we use the tags or they are good practice?

Answer (score 1):

They are specified for adjusting content with respect to screen size.
if you use only col-lg-6 it will display only half screen even on small screen. if you want to display half screen on large devices like desktop, and full size on mobile devices, you have to write col-lg-6 col-sm-12

Comment: And if I don't write it at all? the Bootstrap still handles it without me writing the classes. So, where is the actual use?

Comment: refer this link, related projects are declared col-lg-3 for large devices and col-xs-12 for smaller devices. if you don't specify col-lg-3, it will take by default col-lg-12

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap grid is divided into 12 blocks.
With `xs, sm, md, lg` classes you can set how your content will look on different resolution.
Each class has set percent of width on different resolutions. e.g.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

You can set that on normal resolution block will take half a row `col-md-6`, but on small resolution it will take fill row width: `col-sm-12`.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Content</div>
```